# Weekend Date return issue

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

So I have this:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Friday 17:00'));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+2 days", strtotime('Friday')));
$conditions['scope'] = " (event_start_date BETWEEN CAST('$start_date' AS DATE) AND CAST('$end_date' AS DATE)) OR (event_end_date BETWEEN CAST('$end_date' AS DATE) AND CAST('$start_date' AS DATE))";
```

I want the dates to output for the coming weekend (Fri at 1700 - Sun), which it does until I get to Friday, then it starts to show the next weekend.

How can I get it to show the current weekend until end of Sunday when it then shows the next weekend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Sunday'));
$start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end_date . ' -2 days '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strToTime('this Sunday'));
```

Here is the reference for [strToTime's relative dates](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: You need to go back from the `$end_date`.
`$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date . ' -2 days'));`

Comment: @andho - didn't think '-2 days' was necessary because 'Friday 17:00' already returns Friday's date.  But yes you Sir are correct.  `strToTime()` is like a cat, many ways to skin it.